# Don't run second job when first job fails in concourse

Tags: devops, concourse, concourse-pipeline, concourse-fly

I am new to concourse and created one concourse pipeline having 2 jobs that are running sequential.

Is there a way to not run second job when first job fails?

I know that i can handle this at task level, but can i handle this at job level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the `passed` attribute of the [get step](https://concourse-ci.org/get-step.html#get-step-passed) in the job definition. But, that requires a common resource to be used in the get step.

```
jobs:
  - name: job0 
    plan:
      - get: resource0
      - task: ...
  - name: job1
    plan:
      - get: resource0
        passed: [job0]
      - task: ...
```